service worker not working for .tsx/.jsx file in react vite.why?
console.log("service worker");

const OFFLINE_ASSETS = [
  "/",
  "/src/main.tsx",
  "/vite.svg",
  `https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRmCy16nhIbV3pI1qLYHMJKwbH2458oiC9EmA&s`,
];

const addResourcesToCache = async (resources) => {
  const cache = await caches.open("v1");
  await cache.addAll(resources);
};

self.addEventListener("install", (e) => {
  console.log("installing");
  e.waitUntil(addResourcesToCache(OFFLINE_ASSETS));
});

const cacheFirst = async (req) => {
  const responseFromCache = await caches.match(req);
  if (responseFromCache) {
    return responseFromCache;
  }

  return fetch(req);
};

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(cacheFirst(event.request));
});

it's displaying "index.html" on "/" which ii should . the svgs and images link are also working but only main.tsx and such arent working when i close my server . why ?
its on react-ts on vite

src/main.tsx is a source file. when you access files trough the webbrowser you are typically only able to access public files (the files in your dist/ folder when you do vite build)
the main.tsx file is not in there because the source code of your site is often sensative information that you dont want random people to be able to read
normally the compiler compiles the tsx files into raw html/js/css that is bundled together in minimized files. those files are the ones ending up being distributed in /dist/
if you (for some reason, not recommended) want that main.tsx file to be copied to your dist folder without being altered in name and content. you could use vite-plugin-static-copy. which is a plugin meant to copy static files into your build output
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-static-copy

i wanted to display an some components when the server or internet gooes offline . so whats would be the best way to achieve this ?

What exactly do you mean? when the internet goes offline, you simply cant reach remote servers. and if you have the file locally already, its local so you can reach it anyways

I wanted to display an offline version of the page when the internet goes out just like how YouTube (web version) display no internet page when there is no internet

I think your page caching works fine like you wrote it. The issue is that you cant load raw typescript from your serverside. Unless you follow my solution given in my answer. In which case you can.
